# how can I use tf.exe to checkin single file without getting popup dialog box?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, tfs, tf-cli

I'm trying to do a checkin of a single file from the command line using tf.exe:

tf.exe checkin myfile.cs

But whenever I do, I get a popup dialog asking me to select source files.

How can I get it to checkin just this single file without getting the dialog?
[Popup dialog that hapopens when I try to do a checkin from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aimHe.jpg)

Comment: Do you know what TFS version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the `/noprompt` parameter.

[Check in a change to a single item without using the Check In dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=vsts#check-in-a-change-to-a-single-item-without-using-the-check-in-dialog-box):

```
 c:\code\SiteApp\Main>tf checkin program.cs /noprompt
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are seeing the popup because you aren't adding a comment. There may also be other policies your administrator request, but comment is the one normally required. As noted in the [tf command-line documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=vsts), you can specify a comment as follows:

```
tf.exe checkin /comment:"My comment" myfile.cs
```